# Syntax error in insert into statement(MS.net code with MS Access database)

Tags: .net, sql, ms-access

I got an error on running this code. The error exist where i am using the "insert into" statement. I cant understand what is the problem.

ERROR: Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement

Please tell me where is the problem in the given code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace GTC
{
    public partial class Adminhome : Form
    {
        public Adminhome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=|DataDirectory|/GTC.accdb;");




        void clear()
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            comboBox1.Text = "-Select-";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox5.Text = "";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cn.Open();
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'GTCDataSet2.Society' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.SocietyTableAdapter.Fill(this.GTCDataSet2.Society);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'GTCDataSet2.User' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.UserTableAdapter.Fill(this.GTCDataSet2.User);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                String q = String.Format("insert into Society values('{0}')", textBox5.Text);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, cn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                label8.Text = "Society Added...";
                clear();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                label8.Text = err.Message;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                String q = String.Format("insert into User values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", textBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, cn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                label6.Text = "User Added...";
                clear();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                label6.Text = err.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got two INSERT statements in the code, does the error occur when you click button 1 or button 2?  I would suggest display the contents of string Q after the format statement to see what is shows.   I suspect it is a quoting issue, but could tell better if we knew what the statement actually looked like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no so sure but what I know in VB .. SQL Insert Syntax is

```
 INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
```

I'm not using your style but maybe you've been missing those field list ..

Comment: The field list is optional if you are providing values for every field in the table...